# Data row is too long in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have faced an issue regarding Data Row length exceeded fro SysMaxRow in Teradata Select Query.

Is there any way to look for SysMaxRow?
Can it be increased?

Answer (score 0):

This is an internal system limit, there's no way to increase it (but TD14.10 will have a higher limit).

It might be due to different reasons, e.g. ORDER BY on large VarChars or large VarChars in LATIN and a session requesting data in UTF.